# Can't connect to cockroachdb on gcp

Tags: cockroachdb

I deployed a CockroachDB cluster on a 4 gcp instances in a secure mode and configured a TCP proxy load balancer to distribute the traffic, but when I try to connect to it through the load balancer sometimes I get connected but most of the times I get a connection timeout with this error message in the instances cockroachdb logs:

```
‹http: TLS handshake error from 130.211.1.145:50475: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake›
```

The 130.211.1.145 address in the error message is the gcp LoadBalancer's IP address.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the TC/P proxy load balancer a google cloud load balancer?

Comment: yes, it's a Google  TC/P proxy load balancer.